# Fibonacci sequence using only anonymous lambdas

Tags: c#

I had an interview question and had absolutely NO idea how to solve it.

I guessed that it has something to do with recursion but I'm not too familiar with delegates to implement it.

Comment: Microsoft's Bart de Smet did a blog post on this (http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/11/08/jumping-the-trampoline-in-c-stack-friendly-recursion.aspx). I'm wondering what kind of company expects C# devs to know this offhand though as this is not even remotely useful in everyday situations.

Comment: I totally agree with @kirill-shlenskiy. This kind of skill is not only useless, it's dangerous. If someone were to create this and put it in a project, I would not be very happy. Maintenability and readability and much more important than the having an implementation using only lambdas. Otherwise, you end up with read-only code.

Comment: Very interesting question. I have been working in c# for quite a few years and did have to think about this one quite a bit, so I don't think it's something that should make/break an interview. In the end, this knowledge depends on your programming skill as much as does it on theoretical thinking. Not all jobs require this level of theoretic and abstract thought. I hardly ever encounter this, and if I do, it's a particular problem and you can get a solution if you think hard about it.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding what 'anonymous lambdas' means?  Couldn't you simply do a (long n) => { ...iterative code to compute fibonacci(n)...} - would that not meet the stated goal?

Comment: Unless someone works out how to not compute overlapping sub-problems, it's not just going to be unreadable and unmaintainable. It's also going to run *forever*.

Comment: @Spike "run forever"? Beauty of this code is you can wire up memoization  very easily and get expected linear time. (I'm not saying we should run and replace all code with anonymous lambdas, but knowing about  technique is useful)

Comment: BTW, there are search engines to find samples/explanations (which maybe another skill tested by the question) - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+anonymous+lambda+fibonacci. As interviewer I'd consider posting to SO to be failure to find an answer.

Comment: @Alexei Well, yeah, it's doable, but I didn't see anything in the links or the accepted answer where someone actually did it. (I'll admit I might have missed it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `Y` here refers to the Y combinator ([fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)). You can read more there to understand why the Y combinator works, but, essentially, it enables recursion using anonymous functions.

To answer the question, zero-based Fibonacci can be implemented with the Y combinator and anonymous functions as:

```
Func<int, int> fib = Y(f => x => x < 2 ? 1 : f(x - 1) + f(x - 2));
```

We've given it a name here, but it could just as easily be evaluated using only the expression itself, i.e.:

```
int fib10 = Y(f => x => x < 2 ? 1 : f(x - 1) + f(x - 2))(10);
```

Any recursive function can be implemented in this way. For example, factorial is just `Func<int, int> fac = Y(f => x => x == 0 ? 1 : x * f(x - 1));`.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with that!!! I have to ask this follow up question.... Is that expected from someone who just graduated undergrad with 1 year of work experience? Thank you for the answer btw.

Comment: It depends on what you interviewed for (e.g. a theory-heavy research position), but personally, I don't see much value in this question. It's a test of CS theory, but for typical day-to-day programming, design, architecture, etc., this doesn't reveal much in a candidate one way or another. I wouldn't ask it.

Comment: Thank you... regardless it was a interesting read. Guess I have more to read up on.

Comment: I like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx version of the explanation... If I'd ask such question (assuming code in the post provided as part of question) I would expect at least some attempt around "ohhh it needs function that take function and returns function... that would be something like `func => (x => func(x))` ... maybe pass to that `Y` method..." .